Stream both IceCast and Shoutcast simultaneously on Ubuntu 20.04
My question is the following: Can I stream both IceCast and Shoutcast simultaneously on Ubuntu 20.04
I installed AzuraCAst on Ubuntu server 20.04 downloaded the Shoutcast DNAS for Linux 2.6.1 Build 777. The Azuracast was installed with Docker and running Icecast (2.4.4) with 2 mounts (mp3 320 kbps & AAC 64 kbps)
These are the steps that I've taken.
Method 1: Using DarkIce
sudo nano /etc/darkice.cfg

Then I did this.
[general]
duration = 0          # Infinite duration  
bufferSecs = 5        # Buffer size in seconds  
reconnect = yes       # Reconnect on disconnection  

[input]  
device = icecast      # Use Icecast as the input  
server = 127.0.0.1    # Your Icecast server address  
port = 8000           # Icecast port  
mountPoint = /stream  # Icecast mount point   
sampleRate = 44100    # Audio sample rate  
bitsPerSample = 16    # Bit depth  
channel = 2           # Number of channels  

[shoutcast-0]
bitrateMode = cbr
bitrate = 128
server = 127.0.0.1    # Shoutcast server address
port = 8888           # Shoutcast port
password = your_password_here
mountPoint = /stream  # Shoutcast mount point
name = YourRadioName

I tried:

Dark ice Method
The Liquidsoap Method
The ffmpeg
Using Icecast Stream Relay
SHOUTcast Transcoder (sc_trans)

I keep getting bunch of error and basically it never works. On the Shoutcast server it shows This stream is configured but has no source connected.
With my current configuration how can I have the same IceCast stream http://internal_IP:8000/radio.mp3 to stream to my shoutcast that's already installed and set up via port 8888.

